# Open-Source musical instrument synthesiser

Tags: open-source, music

I am planning on creating a new music band where we use only computer synthesised instruments. So I and my friends decided to use only open-source software.

So, can anyone please recommend me an open-source musical instrument synthesiser?

We currently will be using only bass, guitar and drums, but it would be better if it synthesises more. It's alright if there are different softwares for each intrument, instead of one such software.

We haven't decided the OS we will be using yet, but we are ready to use Windows and/or Linux (Android, Ubuntu, Fedora or OpenSUSE).

Comment: You want some sort of MIDI composer?

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you try downloading and exploring an [ArtistX](http://archiveos.org/artistx/) live image, it provides a wide range of FOSS music production software including:

- Free Audio Synth Software: amSynth, Freebirth, Horgand, Hydrogen, Ingen, Mx44, Psychosynth, Qsynth, Rakarrack, SetBfree, Sineshaper, Yoshimi
- Free Audio MIDI Tools: Arpage, MusE, Patchage
- Free Audio Sound Editor Software: Audacity, Kwave, Rezound, Sweep, Wavesurfer
- Free Audio DAW and Tracker Software: Ardour, Jokosher, Lmms, Rosegarden, Traverso, Wired

It will give a chance to ***play*** with, *in both senses,* a wide range of what is available.

Answer (score 1):

There is [ZynAddSubFX](http://zynaddsubfx.sourceforge.net/).

- It is open-source, licensed under GPL.
- It supports both Linux and Windows.
- It comes with many predefined instruments, and you can also create custom instruments.